# Disprove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x} = c \in R$ using formal finite limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to disprove : $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x} = c \in R$$ using epsilon-delta definition. So here is what I've done :

I know that $c>0$ ( because $\frac{1}{x}>0$ if $x>0$ ).
So applying $\epsilon ,\delta $ definition to check whether the limit is verified , namely : $$\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists\,\delta >0 \,\backslash\,0<x<\delta\Rightarrow-\epsilon<\frac{1}{x}-c<\epsilon$$ 
So taking $0<\epsilon<c$ :

$$-\epsilon<\frac{1}{x}-c<\epsilon  \Rightarrow \frac{1}{c-\epsilon} < x < \frac{1}{c+\epsilon}\;$$ which is a contradiction of  $x \rightarrow0^+$  if $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ . So this limit can't be finite.

Is this reasoning correct? How can I write it in a more formal way that the last inequality implies a contradiction?

Comment: Your definition looks wrong - a condition on $x$ and $\delta$ should imply a condition on $1/x$ and $\epsilon$, not the way you have it

Comment: Oops , you're right , what a mistake ahah

Comment: @bounceback Is this making my reasoning wrong , right from the start ?

Comment: I believe so, the answers below both have it correct. Note that 'if' or 'whenever' means the same as $\Leftarrow$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  I would fix up the language to be more precise and conventional.

You want to show that it is *not* true that **there exists** $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that **for all** $\epsilon > 0$ **there exists** $\delta > 0$ such that **for all** $x$, $0 < x < \delta \implies \left|\frac{1}{x}-c\right| < \epsilon$.

When you negate a quantified statement, the quantifiers get flipped.  So you want to show: **for all** $c \in \mathbb{R}$, **there exists** $\epsilon > 0$ such that **for all** $\delta > 0$, **there exists** $x$, such that $ 0 < x < \delta$ and $\left|\frac{1}{x}-c\right| \geq \epsilon$.

You wrote “taking $0 < \epsilon < c$,” but I would recommend being specific.  You are trying to satisfy a “there exists” quantifier, so point one out.  $\epsilon = \frac{c}{2}$ works pretty well.

Now, given $\delta > 0$, you want to find $x$ such that $0 < x < \delta$ and $\left|\frac{1}{x}-c\right| \geq \frac{c}{2}$.  As long as $0 < x < \frac{1}{2c}$, then $\left|\frac{1}{x}-c\right| > c > \frac{c}{2}$.  So let $x$ be the minimum of $\frac{1}{2c}$ and $\frac{\delta}{2}$.  That way both $0  < x < \delta$ and $0 < x < \frac{1}{2c}$ are satisfied.

This takes care of the case that $c > 0$.  What about $c = 0$?  (You asserted that the limit must be positive; that's not true.)  $c < 0$?

Comment: Thank you ! The fact that $\frac{1}{x}>0$ if $x>0$ doesn't imply that $c>0$?

Comment: Or this implies at least that c >= 0 ?

Comment: No, I don't think it does.  For instance, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ Take $\epsilon = 1.$ Suppose for that $\epsilon$ ($>0$) you have $\delta > 0$ such that $$\left |\frac 1 x - c \right | < 1,\ \ \text {whenever}\ 0 < x < \delta.\  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ Now find $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $0 < \frac {1} {c+n} < \delta$ (This is possible due to Archimedean property of real numbers). What will happen if we put $x = \frac {1} {c+n}$ in $(1)$? Doesn't it give you a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

In context:

Sequential definition.

Let $x_n >0$, $n,n_0,n_1$ are positive integers.

Want to show that for $x_n \rightarrow 0^+$:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{x_n}=L$;

Let $x_n=1/n$;

$\epsilon >0$ given.

Assume there is a $n_0$ s.t. for $n \ge n_0$

$|\dfrac{1}{x_n}-L|=|n-L|< \epsilon$.

$-\epsilon +L< n <\epsilon +L.$

Archimedean principle : There is a $n_1$ s.t.

$n_1 >\epsilon +L$.

For $n \ge N= \max(n_0,n_1) $

$n < \epsilon +L$ is a contradiction .